# Plotting AUC score for multiple model for multiclass classification in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, auc

I am doing a multiclass classification problem. There are a total of 46 unique classes in my dataset. I have computed the AUC sore for all the class and plot it but I want to plot my AUC score for different types of models in one graph means I want to plot my graph for LogisticRegression, XGBoost and 2 more which is used to solve the multiclass problem. My code what I have done till-

```
n_classes = 46
best_C =1000
best_gamma =0.0001
svc_model_grid_param = SVC(C=best_C,  kernel="rbf", gamma= best_gamma, )

model_OVR_svc = OneVsRestClassifier(svc_model_grid_param)
y_score = model_OVR_svc.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_valid)


# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()

 # calculate dummies once
y_test_dummies = pd.get_dummies(y_valid, drop_first=False).values

for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ =  roc_curve(y_test_dummies[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

### Plotting--

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

lists = sorted(roc_auc.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples

x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.xlabel('Class')
plt.ylabel('AUC Score')

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

### Graph--

[image]

### What I want to do--

[image]

Can anyone help me to do this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably mean *labels* not classes?

Comment: I have total of 46 unique classes which is used here as labels

Comment: Please see how to create a [MCVE]. This is essentially just a `matplotlib` question, asking how to combine different plots into one; the exact details of these plots (e.g. being AUC or anything else, as well as where exactly they come from) are actually irrelevant to what is being asked. Being able to focus and specify exactly your question and removing essentially unnecessary stuff (SVMs etc) is crucial for getting a valid answer.